# Why ignite's RAM not release?

Tags: ignite

When i delete 50 million data, my RAM is not change, but my disk is decrease. 
when is ignite releases the RAM?
I try to shutdown the node of ignite, the RAM is changed very fast. I want to release my RAM when i
delete my data.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite will not release RAM that it does not use. We never considered this scenario as priority: we only expect amount of data to go up :)

Comment: when is use,  the RAM will release?

Comment: Ignite will not release off-heap RAM, as far as I know.

Comment: If off-heap RAM  changes too large, what happen?

Comment: You will catch `IgniteOutOfMemoryException`! But that will not happen if you delete data, only when you insert data, and only if persistence is disabled.
Also, if your data region is too large, your OS may ask you out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Decide beforehand how much RAM space is to be allocated to an Ignite node and set the value as `maxSize` in a [data region configuration](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/memory-architecture/data-regions#adding-custom-data-regions).

Study [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Ignite+Durable+Memory+-+under+the+hood) if you'd like to learn the internals of memory management in Ignite.